# Why SafePoint threadSafe?(concurrency in practice )

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety, safe-publication

I am reading the concurrency in practice.
There is following example(4.3.5):

```
@ThreadSafe
public class SafePoint { 
    @GuardedBy("this") private int x, y;
    private SafePoint(int[] a) { this(a[0], a[1]); }
    public SafePoint(SafePoint p) { this(p.get()); }
    public SafePoint(int x, int y) { 
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    public synchronized int[] get() { return new int[] { x, y };
    }
    public synchronized void set(int x, int y) { this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

Author acts that `SafePoint` - thread safe - I don't understand why. I don't see happens before that guarantee this. After constructor termination, another thread can see `SafePoint` instance underconstructed.

**example:**

```
SafePoint racePublishedSafePoint; //field

 //thread 1:
 racePublishedSafePoint = new SafePoint(1,1);

 //thread 2:
 SafePoint sp;
 while(true){
   SafePoint sp = racePublishedSafePoint;
   if(sp != null) break;
 }
 System.out.println(sp.get()[0]);
 System.out.println(sp.get()[1]);
```

I believe that there is several posiiblle outcomes:

1. application doesn't finish
   **else** if application finished
2. we can see
    a) 0 0
    b) 0 1
    c) 1 0
    d) 1 1

Am I right?
If true, why author marked class as thread safe?
I thought that thread-safe class - class which can be used in concurrent application without sophisticated analyze.

What did author want to say?

---

Also in book I have read following note:

> The private constructor exists to avoid the race condition that would
>   occur if the copy constructor were implemented as this(p.x, p.y); this
>   is an example of the private constructor capture idiom (Bloch and
>   Gafter, 2005).

It is not clear for me  too.

why we need 3 constructors and one of them private?

Please clarify these things.

Comment: Yes, partial state can be observed if the object is published unsafely after constructor. However, that is usually not a concern that we need to guard against. For example, the thread-safe class `Vector` has the same issue. This issue can be fixed, if you must, by surrounding constructor body with `synchronized(this)`

Comment: @Andreas - OP is really asking a different question, regarding safe-publication

Comment: I think the fact that the `get()` method is `synchronized`, means you will see the latest values. Is your concern that the latest values may still be in the middle of being updated by the constructor?